# Check if $ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log(n)^2} $ diverges or converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Check if the following series diverges or converges:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\log(n)^2}
$$
I know that I'm able to compute it using Integral test... But can I use Limit comparison test, with my $b_n = \log(n)^2$?

I know that the series with the sequence $b_n$ is divergent by the test of divergence ($\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b_n \neq 0$).

Applying the limit comparison test I'll get:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{\frac{\log(n)^2}{\log(n)^2}}\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{1} = 1
$$

And because of that my first series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\log(n)^2}$ will diverge too.

Is that correct?!

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to start the sum from $n=2$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yeah, I'll correct that. Sorry. But is what I've done correct?

Comment: $(\log n)^2$ and $\log(n^2)$ are both unambiguous as to what is being squared. $\log(n)^2$ may be problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not applied the limit comparison test correctly.  It should read

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{\log^2(n)}}{\log^2(n)}\lim_{n\to\infty}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\log^4(n)}=0$$

And the limit comparison test does not work for limits that end up to be infinite or $0$.

---

We have the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{\log^2(n)}>\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{\log^2(2^n)}=\frac1{\log^2(2)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n}{n^2}$$

Now all you need is the [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) to finish this off.

Comment: Thanks. O just want to check if that was possible.. what you've just said makes a lot of sense. TY

Comment: No problem :-)  (also, I love using Cauchy condensation test for any series involving logarithms.  Best way to deal with them IMO)

Comment: Thank you for that mate! I'll read about it...

Answer (score 0):

$(\log n)^2 \leq n$, by comparison...

Your limit comparison test doesn't look right. If you had the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}$ instead, and set $b_n = n^2$, then
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac{n^2}{n^2}} = 1
$$
but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}$ is convergent.

Comment: Yeah, I know that too... I just want to check If by the limit comparison what I've done is indeed correct!

Comment: @BrunoReis I am not sure if I understood your question. See the edit.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Oh mate, if I did It wasn't on purpous! Your explanation is good. It's just because the other one is a little bit more clear. I'll upvote urs. I don't think that I've downvoted yours! Thanks